# Button going from first frame to second frame works, but a button going from a second frame to a third frame does not

Tags: python, tkinter

So I am messing around with frames and trying to switch between them. I have two buttons, one in the starting frame, taking you to the second frame, and one in the second frame taking you to the third frame. The button works in the first frame, but not the second frame.

```
# Imports
from tkinter import * # Tkinter is a GUI toolkit used for Python. This toolkit allows me to create the window and many of the UI options
import Pmw # Pmw stands for 'Python mega widgets'. I imported this primarily for tooltips so the user knows what everything means

# Windows
root = Tk() # Root is the main window where I will be putting everything
root.title('Nation Creator') # The title is the text at the top of every window
root.geometry("800x600") # This sets how big the window will be.

#Fonts
titlefont = ("Aldrich", 48)
subtitlefont = ("Aldrich", 22)
font = ("Aldrich", 12.5)

# Functions

#This is so that the user can scroll thru the next frame.
def nextframe(frame):
    frame.tkraise()


# Frames

# These two commands allow the different frames to work
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

#There will be 4 different frames.
titleframe = Frame(root)
titleframe.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='nsew')

politicalframe = Frame(root)
politicalframe.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='nsew')

econframe = Frame(root)
econframe.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='nsew')

miscframe = Frame(root)
miscframe.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='nsew')

for frame in (titleframe, politicalframe, econframe, miscframe):
    frame.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='nsew')

# Section Headings
# These will be the headings for the sections.
# There will be 4 sections; Title Section, Political, Economic, and Micellanious 

title = Label(titleframe, text = "Nation Creator")
title.configure(font = (titlefont))
version = Label(titleframe, text = "Version 1.0")
version.configure(font = (subtitlefont))
startbutton = Button(titleframe, text = "Begin", command=lambda:nextframe(politicalframe))

politicaltitle = Label(politicalframe, text = "Political Section")
politicaltitle.configure(font = (titlefont))
politicaldesc = Label(politicalframe, text = "This is where your nation's name, flag, territory, \nand political and personal freedoms are entered.")
politicaldesc.configure(font = (subtitlefont))
polcontbutton = Button(politicalframe, text = "Begin", command=lambda:nextframe(econframe))

econtitle = Label(econframe, text = "Political Section")
econtitle.configure(font = (titlefont))
econdesc = Label(econframe, text = "This is where your nation's name, flag, territory, \nand political and personal freedoms are entered.")
econdesc.configure(font = (subtitlefont))

#Frame Initialization
nextframe(titleframe)

# This is where I will 'pack' or place everything
title.pack()
version.pack()
startbutton.pack()
politicaltitle.pack()
politicaldesc.pack()
econtitle.pack()
econdesc.pack()

polcontbutton.pack()

# Making sure the window will stay up
root.mainloop()
```

I have no clue what is going on. I have tried to copy and paste the first button's code to make the second, same result. Can someone please help me?

Comment: You're gonna laugh. Your code is perfect. The problem is that your econ frame is an exact copy of your political frame, so when the frame changes it still looks the same. Try changing the econ frame text.

Comment: So as it turns out, the only problem was that my third frame looks exactly like the second, so it looks like the frames arent changing but they are. Thank you, Novel